# Python Pillow: First chessboard row

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a chessboard with Pillow for a small but complicated project of mine. I'm new to Pillow and I'm trying to follow the documentation, that's how I got to this point. My issue is that my code does not work as intended, I'm trying to create a 200x200 image and the first row of the board, but my code does not switch between the colors (red and blue) to create different colored squares.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image_size = 200

with Image.new("RGBA", (image_size, image_size)) as im:

    x, y = 0, 0
    w, h = 50, 50

    red = "RED"
    blue = "BLUE"

    color = red

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

    for i in range(0, int((image_size/5)), 10):
        draw.rectangle((int(i/10) * w, y, w, h), color)

        if color == red: color = blue
        else: color = red

im.show()
```

Expected result:

[image]

Actual result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to:

```py
#....

    for step in range(0, image_size // w):
        draw.rectangle([step * w, y, (step + 1) * w, h], color)

        if color == red:
            color = blue
        else:
            color = red

#....
```

this way you'll be drawing a square for each iteration starting at `step*w` and ending at `(step+1)*w`

Answer (score 0):

You use `draw.rectangle(x, y, w, h)`, but Pillow expects you to specify the lower right corner, which would be `draw.rectangle(x, y, x + w, y + h))`:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image_size = 200

with Image.new("RGBA", (image_size, image_size)) as im:

    x, y = 0, 0
    w, h = 50, 50

    red = "RED"
    blue = "BLUE"

    color = red

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

    for i in range(0, int((image_size/5)), 10):
        x = int(i/10) * w

        print(x)
        print(y)

        draw.rectangle((x, y, x + w, y + h), fill=color)

        if color == red:
            color = blue
        else:
            color = red

im.show()
```

Comment: Got it. I thought the last two variables represent the width and the height of the rectangle, so I was wrong. Thank you!